# Magallanes - Translation from Quechua

Tags: translation, magallanes

In the 2014 movie [Magallanes](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4072352/), the female lead character Celina, played by actress [Magaly Solier](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm2008680/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t12), talks/rants in [Quechua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quechua) from 1:40 to 1:41 (scene at the police office when she and Magallanes are arrested).

I saw the movie with English subtitles but this part was not translated. Some people speculate that this is on purpose, like in [this blog post](https://itpworld.wordpress.com/2016/04/22/viva-22-5-magallanes-peru-argentina-columbia-spain-2015/):

> I was most struck in watching the film by a scene towards the end of the film in which during an argument Celina begins to speak in Quechua, the language spoken by many indigenous people. The dialogue is not translated in the English subtitles and as the audience we can’t be sure if the European Peruvians who speak Spanish understand this outburst. But in a sense it doesn’t matter. Some people prefer not to think about the past, others try to hide it.

I would still like to know the English translation, though. Who has/knows one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments to [this Youtube fragment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=foDDmYeXh5E) contain a Spanish translation by Antonio Muñoz Monge:

> Dinero, plata, en la cabeza de ustedes sólo dinero, sólo dinero.
>   ¿Dándome esto ustedes van a curarme de todo lo que me han hecho?
>   A mi padre, a mi madre, ¿van a hacerlos vivir con este dinero?
>   Desde el inicio, ustedes han hecho lo que les ha dado la gana con mi persona. Mis derechos los han pisoteado.
>   ¿Para qué estoy aquí? ¿ah? ¿Para qué estoy aquí? ¿Hasta cuándo voy a esperar?
>   Mis derechos están pisoteando, ahora también.
>   Ya no siento miedo de ustedes, ni de ti, ni de él, ni de nadie.

[This post](http://elcomercio.pe/redes-sociales/facebook/magallanes-dijo-magaly-solier-monologo-quechua-214486) gives a slightly different translation, stating that it does the rounds on Facebook:

> Dinero, plata, en la cabeza de ustedes solo dinero, solo dinero.
>   ¿Dándome esto ustedes van a curarme de todo lo que me han hecho?
>   A mi padre, a mi madre, ¿van a hacerlos vivir con este dinero?
>   Desde el inicio, ustedes han hecho lo que les ha dado la gana con mi persona. Mis derechos los han pisoteado.
>   ¿Para qué estoy aquí? ¿Ah? ¿Para qué estoy aquí? ¿Hasta cuándo voy a esperar?
>   Mis derechos están pisoteando, ahora también.
>   Ya no siento miedo de ustedes, ni de ti, ni de él, ni de nadie.

Translated into English (with Googles help):

> Money, silver, in your head only money, only money. Are you going to heal me of all that you have done to me?
>   Will my father, my mother, become live with this money?
>   From the beginning, you have done what you have wanted to do with me. My rights have been trampled on.
>   What am I here for? Ah? What am I here for? How long will I wait?
>   My rights are trampled even now.
>   I am no longer afraid of you, nor of you, nor of him, nor of anyone."